# Como fazer uma seleção de ataques (Jogo)

Tags: c#, array, classes

Estou tentando fazer um jogo simples de console em C# e quero que o jogador escolha 4 ataques para atribuir em seu personagem, ataques esses que herdam a superclasse "Ataque" mas são, cada um, uma subclasse diferente. Como atribuir esses ataques no objeto do jogador já que não é possível manter as características de cada ataque em um vetor genérico do tipo "Ataque"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> já que não é possível manter as características de cada ataque em um vetor genérico do tipo "Ataque"

Essa premissa está errada. O código abaixo é válido e representa o que você precisa.

```cs
void Main()
{
    Ataque[] ataquesDoJogador = new Ataque[] 
    {
        new AtaqueEspecial("Ataque especial", 100, 20),
        new AtaqueExplosão("Granada", 80, 10)
    };
}

abstract record Ataque(string Descrição, int Dano);
record AtaqueEspecial(string Descrição, int Dano, int DanoExtra) : Ataque(Descrição, Dano);
record AtaqueExplosão(string Descrição, int Dano, int ÁreaDoDano) : Ataque(Descrição, Dano);
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso566204#main.cs)

Comment: Consegui, valeu. :D